# Numbers of mails sent for specific automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, history-tracking

Hope you can help me with this.
I'd like to sum up the number of sends for my Welcome Mail.
It's an automated mail (External key: eaf8d645-f94d-556e-fcd2-d6668658d9f5) and the mail is located in my Content Builder (ID: 2648)

My final goal is to compare the amount of mails sent pr. month, as I can see traffic generated by this mail in Analytics has droppet to one fourth of the expected in april and may, and I'd like to be able to see if the number of welcome mail sends from the Marketing Cloud has dropped equally.

As I cannot access any mails from my Content Builder in Tracking/Reports (only Classic Content is showing up) I'm turning to you, hoping any of you might have an idea on how to do this.
In example: Is it possible to populate a Data Extension with this data using a Query?

Hope everything makes sense :)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly get this information from Query Activities, but have you investigated the reporting that's already available. Reporting in the email application is getting more broken as the years pass, but the UI in Analytics Builder has been updated in many places to accomodate Content Builder based emails, at last.

What you sound to be looking for is the Email Performance Over Time report. It doesn't allow selection of Content Builder emails in the Email Application, but does in Analytics Builder.

Would this suffice for your needs?

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrew. By accessing data using in Analytics Builder (and not the broken reporting available in the Email application) I was able to collect the data I needed to move on - I had to use this workaround [link](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000f4NmQAI&title=analytics-builder-reporting-does-not-recognize-content-builder-folders) but besides that everything was easy to manage. Great!

Comment: Haha! (Shakes Head) Thanks for the workaround link. Glad you've moved on.